# How to connect mobile headphones as laptop headphones?

Tags: usb, laptop, headphones, adapter, headphone-jack

My laptop's headphone jack is not working properly. Only one side of headphones is working in that jack. So I want to know is there any way to connect my mobile headphone as my laptop's in simple words I want to connect my headphones (whhich is connected to mobile) to my laptop. I know there are **usb adaptors** and other tools but because of this **Corona situation** I'm unable to buy all of these. Please tell me is there any way to do this by just using Usb and wifi.

Comment: You need to purchase the adapter you need on Amazon or similar site. We cannot adapt your headphones here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an app which works. App is calle AudioRelay. Which can be used if your pc's HP jack is not working. Soundwire is also there to do the same.